# Relativistiv kinetic energy and floating point

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, computer-arithmetic

My function is $E(v)=mc^2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} - 1)$, (*c*=3e8, *m*=1) and I have to calculate it for values of *v* between 1e-6 and 2.99e8.
The point of this problem is floating point precision.

For very small values of *v* the result is *E*=0.  I figured that's because of the root: $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}=1$.

I tried using Taylor: $mv^2/2 + 3mv^4/8c^2 + 5mv^6/16c^4 + 35mv^8/128c^6$, and that works well for small *v* but gives me wrong results for very big values of *v*.

How do I transform *E*(*v*) to a better formula that works for all values of *v*?

Comment: You could multiply and divide by $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}+1$, using the old $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ trick again.

Comment: @kimchilover There was a problem in the main formula that I fixed.

Comment: You should specify what is the tool you are using to perform such numerical computations.

Comment: If something is not clear, then do not hesitate to use the comments to ask for clarification. As this is your very first question, we have very limited information about you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't have a square root routine available. Something you could try...

For simplicity I'll assume $m=c=1$, and call the answer $u$, so we have

$$E(v)=u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}-1$$

We can rearrange this to get:

$$(u+1)^2(1-v^2)=1$$

And we can write it as a root finding problem in $u$:

$$(1-v^2) u^2 + 2(1-v^2)u + (v^2 - 2v) = 0$$

Or, perhaps it's clearer to let $s=1-v^2$ and rearrange,

$$s(u^2 + 2u + 1)-1 = 0$$

You could use any root finding algorithm, to find $f(u)=0$, [Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)'s method iterates:

$$u_{n+1} = u_n - \frac{f(u_n)}{f'(u_n)} = u_n - \frac{s (u_n^2 + 2u_n + 1)-1}{2s(u_n + 1)}$$

With a few iterations that should give you the answer to a decent accuracy, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a formula which is numerically reliable for *all* values of $v$.

The fundamental problem is that relativistic $\gamma$ factor, i.e.,
$$ \gamma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}, \qquad x = \frac{v}{c}$$
is ill-conditioned in the vicinity of $x = 1$. Specifically, the condition number of $\gamma$ satisfies
$$ \kappa_{\gamma}(x) = \left|\frac{x \gamma'(x)}{\gamma(x)}\right| = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \rightarrow 1, \quad x \in [0,1)$$
If $\hat{x}$ is the computed value of $x$, then
$$ \left|\frac{\gamma(x) - \gamma(\hat{x})}{\gamma(x)}\right| \approx \kappa_\gamma(x) \left|\frac{x - \hat{x}}{x}\right| $$
Any rounding errors committed when computing $x$ will be magnified by $\kappa_\gamma(x)$ when computing $\gamma(x)$. The effect is dramatic if $v \approx c$.

However, you can get pretty close to $c$ before this becomes an issue. For $v = 0.999c$ the condition number is still less than 500!

The expression $\gamma(x) - 1$ suffers from subtractive cancellation when $x \approx 0$. The cure is to do a Taylor expansion. The order hinges on the accuracy which you seek.

When is the expression $\gamma(x) - 1$ safe to evaluate? The subtraction $d = a - b$ can be computed safely, when $|a| \ge 2 |b|$ or $2|a| \leq |b|$. In our case the relevant point is $x_0 =\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}} \approx 0.8660$. You can use a Taylor expansion on the interval $[0,x_0]$ and the original expression on the interval $(x_0,1)$.

It is frequently necessary to use multiple expression to cover the domain of a given function. Having a single expression is a rare luxury.